# pandas.read_csv() in a for loop. Why is my code not working for more then 2 cycles?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

It works fine for simple files but not with more complex ones.

My files are not corrupted and they are in the right directory.

I tried it with easy generate files (1,2,3,4... a,b,c,d...).

I put it at Github tonight so you can run the code and see the files.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd


def concatenate(indir='./files/', outfile='./all.csv'):
    os.chdir(indir)
    fileList = glob.glob('*.CSV')
    dfList = []
    '''colnames = ['Time', 'Number', 'Reaction', 'Code', 'Message', 'date']'''
    print(len(fileList))
    for filename in fileList:
        print(filename)
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=0)
        dfList.append(df)
        '''print(dfList)'''
    concatDf = pd.concat(dfList, axis=0)
    '''concatDf.columns = colnames'''
    concatDf.to_csv(outfile, index=None)


concatenate()
```

> Error
>
> Unable to open parsers.pyx: Unable to read file (Error: File not found
>   (/Users/alf4/Documents/vs_code/files/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx)).

But just after more than two files.

Comment: Can you check the file name that causes the error? Maybe there is something wrong with it. I can't see a reason, why it should stop with the 3rd. And the error is straight forward.

Comment: Hey, there are >200 files in this folder and all the same structure some with more lines some with 400 lines. You can see at the code that I displayed the names and have a look at them. I deleted so other files get in first and also after the second loop. But every time after 2 cycles it breaks down.

Comment: The error refers to a 'parsers.pyx'. This is not one of your csv-files. So it looks for something else somewhen. Can you add the ful error-message? Maybe this file is called by `pandas` because it is required for the file reading.

Comment: I updated... and this is a good point because there we can see that he looks for the ./lib in the wrong directory. But why?

Comment: That's funny. The git repo from pandas shows the file in two locations: ./io and /_libs. How did you install the package? With pip? To my knowledge, VS Code uses the Python installation of the system. So I would expect a reference to Python, not /vs_code/...

Comment: This is something I don´t understand too. I installed it via pip but also tried to install conda after it. Well, I have also a mac os here, so I still try it there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry for this question/the wrong topic because it seems not to be a code problem.

It seems that the installation of pandas is bugged. It put it to repl.it to share it here and there it works. At the moment I try to repair the python and pandas installation.

So many thanks to these guys in the comments for the helping.

Answer (score 0):

complex ones? do you mean bigger csv files ?

instead of appendding data to an empty list and then concatenating back to the dataframe, we can do it in a single step, take an empty dataframe(df1), keep appending df to df1 in the loop.

df1=df1.append(df)

and then write it out in the end

df1.to_csv(outfile, index=None)

Comment: Thanks for this nice idea but it didn´t work. Same problem like my code. It seems that the installation of pandas is bugged. It put it to repl.it to share it here and there it works. At the moment I try to repair the python and pandas installation.